# Trying to sort a vector with a lambda but keep getting an "expected expression" error

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, lambda

Here is my code function:

```
template<typename W>
void cut(std::vector<W>& data,  double frac)
{
    auto size = data.size();
    //calculate number of elements to be kept
    int to_stay = floor(frac*size);

    std::sort(data.begin(),data.end(),
          [](const W& a, const W& b)->bool
          {
          return a <b;
          });

    // erase all elements after the last one to be kept
    data.erase(data.begin(), data.begin() + to_stay);
    data.erase(data.end() - to_stay, data.end());
}
```

But I keep getting an error saying:

```
[](const W& a, const W& b)->bool    error: expected expression
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you turn on C++11 or higher?

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Clean compile (C++17) live: https://godbolt.org/z/8zkw24

Comment: gcc version c++/4.2.1,

Comment: @IP25 -- That version of gcc is ancient.  Are you using an old IDE, like maybe Dev-C++?

Comment: when i compile using: g++ -o MichelTriggerModule MichelTriggerModule.cpp MichelCalculationFunctions.cpp `root-config --cflags --glibs`

the error is not there though

Comment: @IP25 You need to upgrade your compiler.  I'd suggest at least version 5.0, but really you should go all the way and get 9.2.

Comment: gcc 4.2.1 - `July 18, 2007`:  Please update:  https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html

Comment: @IP25 AFAICS, gcc 4.2.1 predates C++11 completely (support for C++11 [started in 4.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html)). I'm kind of surprised the compiler is complaining about the lambda and not about the `auto`.  Support for `auto` was [added in 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html), support for lambdas [was added in 4.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/cxx0x_status.html)

Comment: it came as a warning, but it still ran